# How do I get the green key off the shelf in the Dobby level of Lego Harry Potter 2?

Tags: nintendo-wii, lego-harry-potter-years-5-7

I can't get the green key off of the shelf in the Dobby level (Year 6). I have tried everything!

Answer (score 17):

You need to roll (double tap X on Xbox, not sure what the binding is in Wii) with a character into the cabinet to knock the key off the shelf.